# Que faire des questions « presque en doublon » ? What can we do with “nearly duplicate” questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, exact-duplicates

Si je prends l'exemple de [**Amener et emporter**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/amener-et-emporter) et de [**What's the difference between the verbs “amener” and “emmener”?**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/449/whats-the-difference-between-the-verbs-amener-and-emmener) les questions sont différentes mais traitent au final du même sujet.

Ces réponses ([rep1](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/453/86), [rep2](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/469/86) et [rep3](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1826/86)) pourraient toutes avoir été données en réponse aux deux questions et être aussi utiles pour les deux questions, pour autant doit-on fusionner les questions en 1 seule, fermer la question comme doublon ?

---

If I look at [**Amener et emporter**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1824/amener-et-emporter) and [**What's the difference between the verbs “amener” and “emmener”?**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/449/whats-the-difference-between-the-verbs-amener-and-emmener), questions are differents but subjects are nearly the same.

Those answers ([ans1](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/453/86), [ans2](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/469/86) and [ans3](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/1826/86))  could have been posted for the two questions and they could have been usefull for all of ones. Should we mark them as duplicate or merge the questions and answers into one thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En général, si deux questions appellent les mêmes réponses, ce sont des doublons. Ici, nous avons un cas assez typique de quasi-doublon où la question de fond est la même mais les exemples sont différents. Il vaut mieux clore si l'application de la règle aux exemples est immédiate, et conserver les deux questions ouvertes si cette application mérite explication. Dans ce cas, j'estime que l'application à l'exemple mérite une simple confirmation, donc je clos la nouvelle question comme doublon (et j'en profite pour éditer la première pour qu'elle soit plus trouvable).

De plus, j'ai fusionné les deux questions, afin que [la réponse de Benoit](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/449/difference-between-the-verbs-amener-and-emmener-and-also-emporter-and-ap/1826#1826) se retrouve sur la question qui reste ouverte. Cette possibilité n'est ouverte qu'aux modérateurs, et à utiliser avec parcimonie, parce que les réponses reprennent souvent les exemples de la question. Ici, la réponse existante reste lisible sans difficulté, donc la fusion est possible.